# Pandas .qcut giving me unequal bin sizes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a stocks price returns pandas dataframe and I want to calculate the deciles for each date (which is the index). This is the code that I am using:

```
deciles = pd.qcut(stock_returns.rank(method = 'first'), 10, labels = False)
```

However, for each date the bins are uneven, like this example date slice:

```
0.0: 90
0.1: 69
0.2: 44
0.3: 43
0.4: 30
0.5: 23
0.6: 14
0.7: 20
0.8: 21
0.9: 24
```

I have also tried this code, but same happens:

```
deciles = pd.qcut(stock_returns, 10, labels = False)
```

Any help?

Comment: How did you print that result?

Answer (score 0):

`pd.qcut` does not tell you how many things are each bin.  That wouldn't be very useful.  What it returns to you is an array showing which bin the corresponding element would go in.  If 90 was the first value returned, then the first element of `stock_returns` would go in bin #90.

Comment: Yes, I know. What I´m trying to say is that for each row of the new database there should be an equal number of deciles, meaning 100 1s, 100 2s, 100 3s, etc. But there isn´t

Comment: Pardon my skepticism, but I don't believe you.  ;)  Can you show us the code that produced the table you printed?

Comment: OK, hold on.  `pd.qcut` is going to assign deciles to the entire data set.  There is no guarantee that any given subset is going to have the same distribution.  Is that what you're doing?

Comment: Yes, so what I want is that it iterates through each row and assigns a decile to each stock's return, but within the same row values.

Comment: Then you will have to run `pd.qcut` multiple times, once for each group.  `pd.groupby` might help with this, but I don't have the code immediately.

Comment: Perfect! Will try so!